# IE 9 iframe loading indicator

Tags: jquery, iframe, internet-explorer-9

I just updated to IE 9 release today and one problem I am seeing is if the content is changing inside an iframe, so like an ajax form in an iframe, there is no indication that an action is taking place when the form is done the content just changes.

is anyone else seeing these issues or know of where this is speced out.
are there any methods to make the spinner in the address bar work from iframes

for now I am setting the cursor to wait on form submit.

Comment: sorry got distracted by the boss editing now

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this issue so the user has some indication that the page is being processed inside the JS function to submit the form before anything happens I set the cursor to wait.

```
 $('body').css('cursor','wait');
```